# How to split large table in SQL Server that is referenced by many objects?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a fairly large table that holds around 65M records in 20+ columns and we’d like to split that table into two tables that would be easier to manage. 
Main challenge here are many objects that are referencing this table (views, stored procedures, functions and application code) and I don’t want to miss anything.

Here is how I plan to do this – can anyone confirm if this is ok or suggest any improvements.

1. Identify all referenced objects
2. Create new table
3. Copy data
4. Add foreign keys that will connect two tables
5. Review and update all objects one at a time
6. Deploy everything to production
7. Remove unneeded columns from old table

Is there anything I’m missing here?

Comment: Why do you think that two tables are easier to manage than one, especially considering all the issues you've already identified with having two tables? Or to put it another way, why is your table so difficult to manage today? If you explain that, someone may have a solution that avoids all the issues and tasks that you've already identified. If you have Enterprise Edition, you may want to look at [table partitioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188706(v=sql.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me but here are some of the challenges I see with this.

**Deployment** – you need to do this fast enough so that it doesn’t cause any issues in production – if you can pause the production system while you’re working on this it would be great. Otherwise make sure you executed this several times in production

**Identifying all referenced objects** – make sure you don’t miss any. I’d recommend using a free third party tool such as [ApexSQL Search](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx) for looking up database objects but you also need to review your application code.

**Order of execution** – if there are too many objects you need to update, make sure you prepare the scripts in the right order

I wouldn’t remove unneeded columns immediately – let them stay there for some time but make sure you are checking the data regularly.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might be planning to vertically partition (split up columns). If your 65M records represent a lot of historical data, perhaps you want to horizontally partition based on date and create a view to bring them together. That way many external referencing objects will not see a difference. I'm making a few assumptions here about the data usage.

A view might also be useful for vertical splitting.